# meteor - live code update to webpage?

Tags: meteor

I'm curious to know whether Meteor would be suitable for following, and how I would go about writing the code.

I'd like to create a webpage, where by the code in a specific "div" can be hotswapped on the fly to users currently looking at that page. (eg. the div contains some text, but then an image replaces it.) Ideally, the swap would be executed manually by the the webpage's admin through the click of a button, or some code fired off on the server or something. Regular viewers to the webpage would not be able to do this - they only see the live changes on the page.

real-life example:

live internet broadcast is off-air, therefore the "div" contains "off-air" text. live hotswap of code happens when broadcast goes on-air, and the viewers of the webpage now see the html5 broadcast player in the "div" instead. later it is swapped back once the broadcast goes off-air.

I'm completely new to the Meteor platform, so I consider myself a newbie :) Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might better off by using a reactive div using data from a collection (I'm going to use an example with raw HTML but you might be better off implementing your own functionality with what content to display instead: i.e

Basically take advantage of [reactivity](http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity) over hot code swaps

**Client side html code**

```
<template name="home">
    <div>
        {{{content}}}
    </div>
</template>
```

**js code**

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
    MyCollection = new Meteor.Collection("MyCollection")

    Template.home.content = function() {
        if(MyCollection.findOne()) {        
            return MyCollection.findOne().content
        } 
    }
}

if(Meteor.isServer) {
    MyCollection = new Meteor.Collection("MyCollection")

    //Set an initial content if there is nothing in the database
    Meteor.startup(function() {
         if(!MyCollection.findOne()) {
             MyCollection.insert({content:"<h1>Test content</h1><p>Test Data</p>"
         }
    }

    //A method to update the content when you want to
    Meteor.methods({
        'updatecontent':function(newcontent) {
            id = MyCollection.findOne()._id
            MyCollection.update(id, {$set:{content:newcontent}});
            return "Done"
        }
}
```

You can update your content either in the mongo collection or with something like (in your web console, client side or server side javascript):

```
Meteor.call("updatecontent","New content",function(err,result) {
    if(!err) {
         console.log(result)
    }
});
```

Which will update the code live when you use it.

I'm sorry it's quite long but the bulk of it is setting/updating the html. Its actually much nicer than a hot code swap which would refresh the user's page